# Using python comprehensions

Tags: python

This is code to count words in a string.

```
def word_count(text):
    word_count = {}
    for word in str(text).split():
        if word in word_count:
            word_count[word] += 1
        else:
            word_count[word] = 1
    return word_count
```

I'm new to python and I'm given to believe this can be done with one line of code using python comprehensions. 
Can someone help with some code and explanation.

Comment: You could use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) here: `Counter(text.split())`

Comment: _"I'm new to python and I'm given to believe this can be done with one line of code using python comprehensions."_ - Be careful with this kind of thinking. Just because a certain function can be expressed as a list comprehension on one line does not make it better. In fact, in some cases it make for unreadable, obfuscated code.

Comment: @dana you can construct dictionaries in the same way with "dictionary comprehensions". OP, if there is a way to do it as a one liner I would still omit doing so. It would be painfully unreadable and readability of a code should not be sacrificed for a "cool short code snippet".

Answer (score 5):

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(text.split())
```

You can also use `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
word_count = defaultdict(int)
for word in text.split():
  word_count[word] += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Fo better result you may write like that,

```
from collections import Counter
# make your str in lower for avoiding, Hello OR hello are different
text = text.lower()
Counter(text.split())
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I personally do not recommend using a one-liner, it can be done with `str.count`:

```
text = ' ' + 'this is that which is this' + ' '  # spaces on the sides for word separation
word_counts = {word: text.count(' ' + word + ' ') for word in text.split()}
```

Answer (score 1):

[collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is a better choice for real use. Just for fun I add another one line implementation:

```
from itertools import groupby

def word_count(s):
    return dict([(k, len(list(g))) for k, g in groupby(sorted(s.split()))])
```